# PhpExcel работа с датой

Tags: php

[image]Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему,при загрузке данных из CSV формата с датой все в порядке,но стоит загрузить из XLSX начинаются проблемы.

Вот записи в Excell в формате XLSX
Date Last Contacted
8/4/2015
9/4/2016

Вот что получается на выходе

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_last_contacted] => 2008-04-15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_last_contacted] => 2009-04-16
        )

)

$file = $this->upload->file_name;
            $file_path = 'uploads/'.$file; 

            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_path);

            //Load all items from file into array
            $array_contacts = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
            $imported_contacts = array();

            foreach($array_contacts as $key => $cell){
                //Skip header cell
                if($key != 0){
                    if(!empty($cell[0]) && !empty($cell[1])){
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['first_name'] = $cell[0];
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['email'] = $cell[1];
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['phone'] = $cell[2];
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['source_id'] = $cell[3];
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['date_last_contacted'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($cell[4]));
                        $imported_contacts[$key]['visible'] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Если в самом Экселе изменить формат даты на указанный как на скрине,то все нормально отображается что в CSV  что в XLSL.

Comment: так проблема-то где? что вы хотите. ну, можно например передалать все содержимое массива на другой формат. или что?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно какой месяц на выходе.2008 вместо 8 и 15-ый год вместо 20015

Comment: понял :( а вы свми этот массив строите?

Comment: Массив да сам строю!

Comment: а покажите тогда код, может поймем

Comment: Код привел выше

Comment: Надеюсь, последнее :) , сделайте `echo $cell[4]);`

Comment: уже не надо. я понял

Comment: тогда, действительно интересно, какая она была до смены формата

Comment: Вот такой был формат *3/14/2001. Что означает звездочка понятия не имею.

Comment: ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ    Форматы даты, начинающиеся со звездочки (*), будут изменены при изменении формата отображения даты и времени на панели управления. Форматы без звездочки останутся без изменений.

Comment: Если пытаться решать задачу в общем случае, здорово было бы узнавать тип формата ячейки. Если это возможно, то для каждого (номера ?) Формата можно было бы сделать паттерн для datetime функции "получить из формата"

Answer (score 1):

я посмотрел про вашу эту библиотеку для чтения excell. Там написано, что дата там в смоем микрософтовском формате, и чтобы ее перевести в php, есть специальная функция

```
date('d-m-y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell[4]);
```

Comment: Пробовал но получается какая то странная дата на выходе вместо 2015 года 2036-ой,сейчас еще раз проверю